# Use variable as command line input in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I execute this command in my shell script.

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 66 j8 hj g7 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 99 99 99 99 c5 00
```

I want to change the 4 couples of 99 to the same random value I generated,I tried this code but I gut 00. The random function is working fine.

```
random="$(cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c 2)"
echo $random
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 66 j8 hj g7 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 $random $random $random $random c5 00
```

Comment: I think there is something you're not sharing. If the `echo $random` works as expected, then the value will expand correctly in the next line as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that would produce four _different_ random values. That's not what OP said they want.

Comment: side note: why are you generated base64 values where the rest of the input seems to want hex? Don't you want to restrict `random` to a valid hex number?

Comment: If you want the same random value (in `hex`), then do something like `random=$(r=$(od -An -N1 -i /dev/urandom); printf "obase=%d; ibase=%d; %s\n" 16 10 $r | bc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most probably that `cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c 2` doesn't generate a hexadecimal number. Try this way instead:

```
random=$(cat /dev/urandom | head -c 1 | xxd -p)
```

And instead of using `cat` and `head`, it would be simpler and cleaner using just `xxd` (thanks @kojiro for the tip!):

```
random=$(xxd -p -l1 < /dev/urandom)
```

Comment: much shorter than running it though `bc`

Comment: Instead of using dd to limit the length, how about `xxd -p -l1 < /dev/urandom`? (I'm assuming that when OP selected two _characters_ they wanted one octet.)

Comment: @starcorn input redirection: the `xxd` command will read from whatever is on the right side of `<`, in this example `/dev/urandom`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
random=$(printf "%02x\n" $((RANDOM % 256))) # zsh and bash
```

?

BTW, if you do not need a leading zero for hex numbers less than 10, and if it is OK to use Zsh instead of bash, you can also do in the following way, which doesn't need a `$(...)` subprocess:

```
random=$(( [##16] (RANDOM & 16#FF) )) # zsh only
```